# Xcode 8.3.3 not rendering xib - works for some time if I restart Xcode

Tags: xcode

Xcode 8.3.3 not rendering xib - works for some time if I restart Xcode.
It just shows a gray view.

This is clearly a bug, but do you know a fix?

Comment: are you also running the beta versions of Xcode 9 on your development machine?

Comment: I use to have the Beta installed - but I removed both Xcode versions to see if that would help. Now I am running only with Xcode 8.3.3

Comment: I'm wondering if you accidentally saved some of these xib files in Xcode 9 format?  Perhaps try reinstalling Xcode 9 beta, then opening the problematic xib files.  Go to the "File Inspector" for the xib file (along the right edge of the IDE window) and on that pane, you can click on the "Opens In" pop-down menu to change from "Latest Xcode (9.0)" to "Xcode 8.x".

Comment: That is really a good suggestion - thanks!